# Why does gspread keep adding semicolons in front of floats?

Tags: python, gspread

**Expected behaviour:**

Values are written to worksheet cells as floats because they are floats.

**Actual behaviour:**

Sometimes floats end up with a mysterious semicolon in front of them, which isn't possible as if there was a semicolon the program would return errors since the values are converted to floats and that wouldn't be possible for a semicolon. Printing the values doesn't show an extra semicolon in front of the values.

**Errors:**

None, except for the worksheet which as a result of all this cannot divide with the values so I naturally end up with a `#DIV/0` error which is expected.

**Details**

So I'm having this seemingly random problem with gspread where it sometimes adds a semicolon in front of values (from what I can tell only floats), which really messes with my worksheets as they do equations based on these values and I constantly end up with 0div errors because they aren't floats in the worksheets.

I use `sheet.update(range, values)` to write data to the sheet and the values in the data are converted to floats on several occasions just to be sure they'd stay that way. The problem is in no way consistent it can vary cell by cell and worksheet by worksheet but it's still frustrating.

For reference here's an example worksheet:
[image]

When I print the row values it looks like this (no semicolons there):
[image]

I would really appreciate input on this as I have no clue what's happening - is this something usual with gspread? And I should add that I can't use integers instead of floats as the values can be floats - they just don't have decimals in that particular example.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is not due to gspread but rather due to google spreadsheet formatting the cells.

when updating the spreadsheet the values are sent using JSON, which is typed. If your list contains strings then the spreadsheet will see it's a string and not an integer. So it will choose accordingly a cell format for text.

If you change the list of values you send and use integers or floats as:
`['10.07.2022', 70, 110, '14.07.2022', 9, 45]`

then any number will be treated as a number on the spreadsheet.

You'll notice that the apostrophe `'` you see in front of the value is not part of the actual data in your cell if you take the exact same spreadsheet and change the format of the cell to Number, it disappears. :-)